# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero with client cannot decrypt from server

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have the compile error when I run the code.

```
Error: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero
```

At this line testClient.java

```
byte[] newPlainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherTextFromServer);
```

The message encrypted from the server cannot be decrypted by the client.
Is there any wrong in my code?

//TestServer.java

```
public class TestServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    //set variables for port number, RSA key size
    final int port = 3344;
    final int RSAKeySize = 1024;
    final String newline = "\n";
    //set public key, sockets, server text, plain text
    PublicKey pubKey = null;
    PrivateKey priKey = null;
    ServerSocket server = null;
    Socket client = null;
    String serverText = "Hello Client! This is an authentication message from server";
    byte[] plainText = serverText.getBytes("UTF8");
    //initialize RSA
    try {
        System.out.println("Start generating RSA key");
        KeyPairGenerator RSAKeyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        RSAKeyGen.initialize(RSAKeySize,random);
        KeyPair pair = RSAKeyGen.generateKeyPair();
        System.out.println("Finish generating RSA key");
        pubKey = pair.getPublic();
        priKey = pair.getPrivate();
    }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage() + newline);
        System.out.println("Error initialising encryption. Exiting.\n");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    //initialize cryptography, set cipherText
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    System.out.println("RSA cipher object and provider"+cipher.getProvider().getInfo());
    System.out.println("Start Encryption for plainText");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
    System.out.println("Finish Encryption to cipherText: ");
    BASE64Encoder base64 = new BASE64Encoder();
    String encryptedValue = base64.encode(cipherText);
    //String encryptedValue = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(cipherText);
    System.out.println(new String(cipherText,"UTF8"));
    System.out.println("Base64");
    System.out.println(encryptedValue);
    //initialize socket connection
    try{
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        client = server.accept();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error initialising I/O.\n");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    //send server private key
    try{
        System.out.println("Send private key out");
        System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(priKey.getEncoded()));
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
        bb.putInt(priKey.getEncoded().length);
        client.getOutputStream().write(bb.array());
        client.getOutputStream().write(pubKey.getEncoded());
        client.getOutputStream().flush();
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("I/O Error");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    //send cipherText
    ObjectOutputStream obOut = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    obOut.writeObject(encryptedValue);
    obOut.flush();
    client.close();
}
```

}

//TestClient.java

```
public class TestClient {

public static void main(String[] args){ 
    //throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, ClassNotFoundException, 
    //InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    //set variable for port, socket, server public key
    final int port = 3344;
    Socket sock = null;
    Key serverPubKey = null;
    final int RSAKeySize = 1024;
    final String newline = "\n";
    Key priKey = null;
    //setup connection by creating socket
    try{
        sock = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),port);
    }catch(UnknownHostException e){
        System.out.println("Unknown host.");
        System.exit(1);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("No I/O");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    //get public key from server
    try{
        byte[] lenb = new byte[4];
        sock.getInputStream().read(lenb,0,4);
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(lenb);
        int len = bb.getInt();
        System.out.println(len);
        byte[] servPubKeyBytes = new byte[len];
        sock.getInputStream().read(servPubKeyBytes);
        System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(servPubKeyBytes));
        X509EncodedKeySpec ks = new X509EncodedKeySpec(servPubKeyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        serverPubKey = kf.generatePublic(ks);
        System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(serverPubKey.getEncoded()));
        //PrivateKey privateKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes));

    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error obtaining server public key 1.");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("Error obtaining server public key 2.");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        System.out.println("Error obtaining server public key 3.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    try {
        System.out.println("Start generating RSA key");
        KeyPairGenerator RSAKeyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        RSAKeyGen.initialize(RSAKeySize, random);
        KeyPair pair = RSAKeyGen.generateKeyPair();
        System.out.println("Finish generating RSA key");
        priKey = pair.getPrivate();
    }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage() + newline);
        System.out.println("Error initialising encryption. Exiting.\n");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    try{
    //Decrypt message from server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        String message = in.readLine();
        //ObjectInputStream obIn = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
        //Object obj = obIn.readObject();
        System.out.println(message);
        byte[] cipherTextFromServer = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(message);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        System.out.println("Start decryption");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, priKey);
        byte[] newPlainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherTextFromServer);
        System.out.println("Finish decryption: ");
        System.out.println(new String(newPlainText,"UTF8"));
        sock.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: cipherTextFromServer is null/empty?

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks completely broken. You encrypt the data with a public key generated on the server, but then you decrypt it with a private key generated on the client. This will never work, because the key pairs won't match.

To confuse matters further, it seems you try and send keys between the server and the client, but that looks broken too, e.g.

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
bb.putInt(priKey.getEncoded().length);
client.getOutputStream().write(bb.array());
client.getOutputStream().write(pubKey.getEncoded()); // pubKey?!!
```

You should rethink your design entirely. Private keys are not typically generated centrally and distributed outwards. Instead, consider having your client generate a key pair and send its public key to the server, which can use that for encrypting the data.

Comment: But note that just sending the public key is susceptible to man in the middle attacks; you need to establish trust with regard to the public key as well (e.g. by using PKI).

Answer (score 3):

You are ignoring the return value of `InputStream.read()` method.

You are using `ObjectOutputStream` to write the encoded value on the server side and `InputStreamReader` to read it on the client side.

The end result is that `servPubKeyBytes` and `cipherTextFromServer` contain some garbage and when you pass them into the cipher it predictably breaks.

First, fix your I/O code by testing that the client-side reads all the data correctly.

Second, check that encryption and decryption code works by using it in the same application without any kind of I/O.

Third, combine the working I/O with working enc/dec code.